# Can I have CNAME for mailgun when setting up Firebase hosting for my own domain?

Tags: dns, firebase-hosting

I want to have firebase hosting pointing to my owndomain, but I've heard in domain's DNS settings, there is only one CNAME allowed. However, my site also uses mailgun service, so I have to have CNAME for mailgun. Is it allowed? I have been waiting for 10+ hours, and status still shows "Needs setup" :(

```
Type            Host        Value

CNAME Record    email.mg    mailgun.org.
CNAME Record    @           freebies-xxxx.firebaseapp.com.
```

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. However, in the DNS you can have one `CNAME` per label.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks. Per label you mean per host?

Comment: Per record :-) So you can have more than one in your zone, but only one per record, or per host if you wish. My "per label" was imprecise. So you can have `a.example.com CNAME` and `b.example.com CNAME` at the same time. You can not have two CNAME at the same time for `a.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick!!!